# Get Users Email Address with Firebase's Twitter Simple Login

Tags: firebase, firebasesimplelogin

I'm trying to pull the users email address after they authenticate with Firebase's Simple Login Twitter Auth. Right now I'm getting tons of info about the user, but not their email address. I realize with Facebook or Google+ you set the permission like

```
auth.login('facebook', {
  scope: 'email'
});
```

but I can't figure out how to do the same with Twitter.

Comment: Unfortunately the Twitter API doesn't return a user's email, but you can use Firebase's email / password auth: https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-email-password.html

Comment: Hey Sara! Thanks for the comment. I switched to using Facebook/Google+ instead. Go tell Joey Y. his hair is looking great for me. :)

Comment: Glad it's working with FB/G+! I'll definitely pass the message along to Joey :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Sara pointed out in the comments, there is no way to get a users email with Firebase's SimpleLogin Twitter auth. You can however with Facebook or Google+.

Comment: check my answer @Tyler

Answer (score 2):

You can actually get the email using Twitter Auth, its just restricted. Twitter needs to review your TOS and Privacy policy before allowing you to see email, check out the article here: https://medium.com/firebase-developers/twitter-login-authentication-using-firebase-in-android-ded28ca314d2 it explains the issue and resolution somewhere near the end of the article.

Comment: So I did this, and I can confirm that the email address is listed on Firebase Console's Users section... However, the email is still returned as `null` if I console.log the user that is returned from Firebase's SDK in an Angular app. This is odd.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the email'user with twitter and firebase, just follow these steps:

1. Go to: [developer.twitter.com](https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/dashboard)

Then Bellow "Projects And Apps" ==> "default project-17xxx..." ==> "17xxxx..." , click on Edit (see picture):

[image]

[image]

2. Enable Request Email from users:

[image]

3. Fill Fields like that:

[image]

4. For android app, code in java just try  to get data with code:

if (currentUser != null) {

```
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    if (user != null) {
        for (UserInfo profile : user.getProviderData()) {
            if (profile.getProviderId().equals(TwitterAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID)) {
                // UID specific to the provider
                String uid = profile.getUid();

                // Name, email address, and profile photo Url
                String name = profile.getDisplayName();
                String email = profile.getEmail();
                Uri photoUrl = profile.getPhotoUrl();
                Log.i("DEBUG", String.format("uid=%s name=%s email=%s url=%s",
                        uid, name, email, photoUrl));
            }
        }
```